# Rails swfupload and apache configuration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, swfupload

I am trying to use swfupload with rails . I configured everything , passing the session_id and authenticity token in the URL and it works great on my local environment ( webrick ) .

However when I deploy it on production with Apache , everything works fine except the swfupload  . I keep on getting 301 error code . 
After trying http sniffer , I found out that even for urls like :
/docs?id=7 , apache sends a 301 redirecting to /docs/?id=7

Since I am using swfupload , I need to pass the session id and authenticity token in my URLs . Any ideas on how to prevent Apache to send these 301s ? I think I need to make some changes in the .htaccess file present in the public folder of my RAILS_ROOT directory , but I am not sure .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache? if so try turning it off with 
RewriteEngine off in .htaccess and see if that works